# Generate a random length is 12 string that is comprised uppercase and lowercase alpha and numbers

Tags: python, random, passwords, generator

How can I create a Python algorithm to generate a 12 character string comprised of unique uppercase and lowercase alpha and numbers?

In my situation, it would be used as a unique session/key identifier that would *likely* be unique over 500K+ generations.

For example:

```
837uNNM9abCb

9HFRHcop24Cd
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's stopping you writing this yourself?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html), but what have you tried?

Comment: @MitchWheat I have already try to coding for that, but it is duplicate during 500K+ generation.

Comment: @ChrisP Sure, but I have not idea about this pattern (uppercase + lowercase + number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily achieved using a while loop and Python's `random` and `string` libraries.

**Code:**

```
import random
import string

def create():
    _string, counter = "", 0
    while counter < 12:
        choice = random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        if choice not in _string:
            _string += choice
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass
    return _string

print(create())
```

**Output:**

```
YWdTocQs0R4X
```

**What it is doing:**

1. Creating variables `_string` and `counter`.
2. Starting a while loop that breaks after the condition `counter < 12` becomes false.(There is a reason for using a `while` loop over a `for` loop here that I will explain later)
3. Uses Python's random library to find a random number/letter(upper and lowercase).
4. Checks to see if the choice is a already in the string, if it is not, the choice is added to the string. But if it is, nothing happens and the loop starts over again (Why I used a `while` loop over a `for` loop.
5. Returns the string!

**Note:** If you are ok with duplicates WITHIN the string this one-liner works much more efficiently.

```
print(''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for _ in range(12)))
```

Comment: It just only uppercase.
Example string is comprised uppercase and Lowercase alpha and numbers.

Comment: I got it and thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome! :)